# Network traffic when mounting GCP bucket

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, bucket

I'm supporting multiple application clusters, 8 individual clusters, with each cluster is being backed by a mysql instance and an NFS server to share filesystem with application servers. I want to be able to make daily backups of the database and shared filesystem to GCP cloud storage. As I'm looking at this tasks I read that I would be able to create and mount a GCP bucket, like attaching a shared filesystem, to each MySql and NFS server instances. I could also just create the GCP bucket, make local MySql and NFS shared filesystem backups, and then copy them over to the GCP bucket
There are about 12 MySql instances and 8 NFS instances
I would create one GCP bucket and create MySQL and NFS folder with a sub folder for each individual MySql and NFS instance. There would be possibly 2-3 terabytes of data backed up and continuously stored in the bucket.

1. Local backup and copy to bucket
   Would never loose mount
   copying over network using scp
   have local copy to restore from when mount gets lost
2. Mount Bucket
   can loose mount and no local copy
   no copying over network using scp

My concern now is with network traffic. Assume that the GCP bucket including sub folders would contain 2-3 terabytes of data. When mounting the bucket on each MySql and NFS instance each instance would mount, share, all sub folders. ie. each instance would mount all the data, including data that belongs to another cluster.
Does anyone know, approximately:

1. how much network traffic a mounted gcp bucket would take?
2. If mounting this bucket would there be a constant synchronization between the individual MySql/NFS servers and the gcp bucket occure, since the mounted bucket act as a shared filesystem
3. Would it be better, network wise, to copy files from a server to the bucket instead of mounting the bucket?

Thank you for any info.

Cheers,
Roland

Comment: 1) Folders/Directories do not exist in Cloud Storage. 2) gcsfuse will not add noticeable network overhead. 3) I would not use gcsfuse on production systems. 4) You will need to install a tool/utility to measure network bandwidth and usage beyond what Google Cloud Monitoring provides.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley for the info.

Comment: 1) Folders/Directories do not exist in Cloud Storage. 
Correct. But folders/dirs can be created on a VM and then will be uploaded to bucket and shared across all VMs 

3) I would not use gcsfuse on production systems. 
Any specific reason why not? 

4) You will need to install a tool/utility to measure network bandwidth and usage beyond what Google Cloud Monitoring provides.
 Ok, that makes sense. Nload, iftop, etc

Comment: Folders/Directories do NOT exist. The namespace is flat. The part that you think is a directory is just part of the object name. This causes issues that have to be simulated by software that mounts file systems. Examples including directory simulation - lots of files will cause long mount times and the entire bucket namespace must be read into memory. Other issues include file locking, directory cache synchronization between systems, no read/modify/last-access metadata, etc. In a previous life, I wrote file systems and drivers for Unix, Linux, and Windows. gcsfuse is a nice **developer** tool.

Comment: thank you @JohnHanley for the info. I did a trial setup. When backing up a smalish file, 2-3GB to the bucket, no problem. If I try to backup a database snapshot, 50GB, I notice that memory is going pretty low on the test VM and I'm not able to list any existing data on the bucket.. Local backups and then copy backup to bucket might be simplest solution